# worth doing/worth to do/worth to be done

Tags: meaning

1 This car is not worth buying.

1a This car is not worth being bought.

2 This car is not worth it to buy.

2a This car is not worth it to be bought.

I thinks that 1 and 2 are correct. But what's the difference between the 2 and what's the difference between 1 and 1a, 2 and 2a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences 1 and 2 are correct and natural. There's no significant difference between the two.

Sentences 1a and 2a are grammatically correct, but almost meaningless. There's also no real difference between the two.

"Worth" is a relative term, which means it only has meaning relative to some agent, usually a person. In other words, for something to be "worth" something, it must be worth it *to someone*. When you use the passive voice, it obscures who that person is, because it might not be the person buying the car, so "worth" loses any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

1. is correct and idiomatic.

1a. is not idiomatic. You might say that the **car is not worth being repaired** but no native speakers would say **not worth being bought**.

2. and 2a are not grammatical. It's fine to say that **the car is not worth it** (whether you mean to repair or to buy or something else) but you can't add **to buy** or **to be bought**. Just wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 2 is completely grammatically correct.

Comment: @user1425 Yes, it's not wrong, but native speakers wouldn't use that construction.

Comment: How can you speak for all of them?

Comment: @user1425 When speaking of what's idiomatic (natural phraseology by native speakers) there's always room for regional and cultural differences. But in 70 years of writing, speaking and teaching English in 4 continents, I haven't come across 1a. Others may well have.

Comment: I meant sentence 2